# Properly changing the z-index for stacking SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My question is how I can stack `SVG` which are constantly changing width and height via interval?

Explanation:

Once `svg` #1 reaches a specific width and height, it will be reset
to `0` and should be the one with a higher `z-index`.

`SVG` #2 will have a lower `z-index` than `SVG` #1, `SVG` #3 will have a lower `z-index` than `SVG` #2.

`SVG` #27 will have a lower `z-index` than `SVG` #26. Once `SVG` #27 reached a specific height, it will reset and should have
higher `z-index` than `SVG` #1

This should loop via interval.

This is my current code but I don't know the flow of the scenario above:

```js
function getRandomColor() {
 
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
 
  var color = '#';
 
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  
  }
 
  return color;
 
}

setInterval(myMethod, 10);

function myMethod( )
{

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs1').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs1').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs1').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs1 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs1').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs1').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs2').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs2').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs2').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs2 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs2').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs2').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs3').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs3').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs3').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs3 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs3').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs3').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs4').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs4').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs4').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs4 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs4').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs4').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs5').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs5').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs5').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs5 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs5').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs5').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs6').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs6').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs6').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs6 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs6').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs6').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs7').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs7').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs7').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs7 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs7').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs7').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs8').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs8').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs8').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs8 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs8').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs8').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs9').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs9').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs9').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs9 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs9').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs9').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs10').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs10').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs10').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs10 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs10').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs10').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs11').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs11').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs11').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs11 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs11').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs11').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs12').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs12').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs12').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs12 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs12').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs12').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs13').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs13').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs13').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs13 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs13').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs13').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs14').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs14').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs14').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs14 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs14').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs14').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs15').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs15').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs15').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs15 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs15').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs15').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs16').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs16').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs16').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs16 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs16').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs16').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs17').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs17').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs17').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs17 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs17').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs17').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs18').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs18').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs18').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs18 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs18').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs18').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs19').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs19').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs19').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs19 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs19').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs19').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs20').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs20').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs20').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs20 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs20').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs20').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs21').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs21').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs21').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs21 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs21').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs21').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs22').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs22').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs22').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs22 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs22').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs22').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs23').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs23').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs23').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs23 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs23').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs23').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs24').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs24').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs24').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs24 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs24').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs24').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs25').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs25').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs25').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs25 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs25').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs25').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs26').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs26').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs26').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs26 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs26').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs26').css('height','+=2');

}

if(parseFloat(jQuery('.fs27').css('width'))>=5400){

jQuery('.fs27').css('width',0);

jQuery('.fs27').css('height',0);

jQuery('.fs27 path').attr('fill',getRandomColor());

}

else{

jQuery('.fs27').css('width','+=2');

jQuery('.fs27').css('height','+=2');

}

}
```

```css
.heart-container {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: -999;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
}

.rainbow {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.fs1 {
 width: 5200px;
 height: 5200px;
 z-index: 27;
}
.fs2 {
 width: 5000px;
 height: 5000px;
 z-index: 26;
}
.fs3 {
 width: 4800px;
 height: 4800px;
 z-index: 25;
}
.fs4 {
 width: 4600px;
 height: 4600px;
 z-index: 24;
}
.fs5 {
 width: 4400px;
 height: 4400px;
 z-index: 23;
}
.fs6 {
 width: 4200px;
 height: 4200px;
 z-index: 22;
}
.fs7 {
 width: 4000px;
 height: 4000px;
 z-index: 21;
}
.fs8 {
 width: 3800px;
 height: 3800px;
 z-index: 20;
}
.fs9 {
 width: 3600px;
 height: 3600px;
 z-index: 19;
}
.fs10 {
 width: 3400px;
 height: 3400px;
 z-index: 18;
}
.fs11 {
 width: 3200px;
 height: 3200px;
 z-index: 17;
}
.fs12 {
 width: 3000px;
 height: 3000px;
 z-index: 16;
}
.fs13 {
 width: 2800px;
 height: 2800px;
 z-index: 15;
}
.fs14 {
 width: 2600px;
 height: 2600px;
 z-index: 14;
}
.fs15 {
 width: 2400px;
 height: 2400px;
 z-index: 13;
}
.fs16 {
 width: 2200px;
 height: 2200px;
 z-index: 12;
}
.fs17 {
 width: 2000px;
 height: 2000px;
 z-index: 11;
}
.fs18 {
 width: 1800px;
 height: 1800px;
 z-index: 10;
}
.fs19 {
 width: 1600px;
 height: 1600px;
 z-index: 9;
}
.fs20 {
 width: 1400px;
 height: 1400px;
 z-index: 8;
}
.fs21 {
 width: 1200px;
 height: 1200px;
 z-index: 7;
}
.fs22 {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 1000px;
 z-index: 6;
}
.fs23 {
 width: 800px;
 height: 800px;
 z-index: 5;
}
.fs24 {
 width: 600px;
 height: 600px;
 z-index: 4;
}
.fs25 {
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 z-index: 3;
}
.fs26 {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 z-index: 2;
}
.fs27 {
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="heart-container">
<svg class="rainbow fs1" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs2" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs3" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs4" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs5" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs6" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs7" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs8" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs9" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs10" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs11" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs12" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs13" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs14" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs15" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs16" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs17" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs18" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs19" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs20" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs21" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs22" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs23" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs24" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs25" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs26" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg><svg class="rainbow fs27" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
      <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EMMKKb

Comment: I've slowed down the interval a bit for [this demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EMMKKb) but wanted to show that you don't need to repeat the `if` condition for each element if you loop through the common class they have.

Comment: oh yeah forgot about that thanks

Comment: im thinking something like this before https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZwohGfq4Oo

Comment: That looks easy (and lightweight) enough but is also a bit bland. How do you like the beginning of [this idea](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zbgGyK)?

Comment: Well what I'm looking for is what i posted here but at same time lightweight, but I guess it's not possible?

Comment: Alternative approaches I could think of are trying to accelerate hardware on the current code (not sure if that is lacking, repaints and stacking contexts are quite complex), looking to use canvas instead, or engaging a framework designed to do these kinds of animations.

Comment: do you think it can be done with jquery animate?

Comment: I don't think that'll have a major impact on performance, it basically does the same stepped approach that is already used here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to stack `SVG` using `z-index`. The only approach to get an element to be on top is to make it last in the document order. That is possible with jQuery's `appendTo` of course.

From the question I concluded that you were after a continous flow of "growing" overlapping hearts. I've taken the liberty to use `scale` and `requestAnimatioFrame` instead of increasing the width and `setInterval`, both are much better for performance and sparing the machine resources. I removed the last of the 27 elements, it was a lot easier to divide scaling by incremental steps of 25 elements. I've automated the process so it doesn't have to be defined in the style (unless you want to create a fallback).

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RddGYB)

```js
var ratio = {}, speed = 0.001;

function getRandomColor() {

  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';

  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }

  return color;
}

$('.rainbow').each(function(index) {

  var mark = $(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop();
  ratio[mark] = 1-index*0.04;

  $(this).css('transform', 'translate(-50%, -50%) scale(' + ratio[mark] + ')');

});

function myMethod() {

  $('.rainbow').each(function() {

    var item = $(this),
    size = this.getBoundingClientRect().width,
    tag = item.attr('class').split(' ').pop();

    if (size > 5400) {
      ratio[tag] = 0;
      item.appendTo('.heart-container').find('path').attr('fill', getRandomColor());
    }
    else ratio[tag] = ratio[tag]+speed;

    item.css('transform', 'translate(-50%, -50%) scale(' + ratio[tag] + ')');
  });

  requestAnimationFrame(myMethod);
}

requestAnimationFrame(myMethod);
```

```css
.heart-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.rainbow {
  width: 5200px;
  height: 5200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="heart-container">
  <svg class="rainbow fs1" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs2" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs3" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs4" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs5" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs6" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs7" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs8" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs9" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs10" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs11" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs12" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs13" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs14" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs15" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs16" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs17" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs18" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs19" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs20" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs21" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs22" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs23" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs24" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs25" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
  <svg class="rainbow fs26" viewBox="0 0 199.6 184.15">
    <path fill="#4687BF" d="M146.69 0A52.9 52.9 0 0 0 99.8 28.37 52.92 52.92 0 0 0 0 52.91a53 53 0 0 0 .69 8.5C9.47 117.63 99.8 184.12 99.8 184.12s90.33-66.49 99.11-122.71a53 53 0 0 0 .69-8.5A52.91 52.91 0 0 0 146.69 0z"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I would have preferred to keep track of the current scaling by using a `data` attribute on each element but that is not currently supported for `SVG` either. So I've used an object named `ratio` in the script to keep track by using the specific classes and storing their momentary `scale`. I would otherwise have used the order of the initial indexing of the elements for this but that changes when using `appendTo`.

The speed of growth can be set at the top.

Comment: Not sure for what you would want to use this though, it seems to be quite "heavy" even with optimisations. You might want to use less elements. In fact, I'd go about it a bit differently myself - use `transition` and let the rendering engine do most of the work instead of forcing CSS with JS...

Comment: Actually, since I thought it was an interesting experiment, I've [made a script](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PLLOyK) that only uses `transition` and barely forces any JS on the style. Even with 10 elements only, it seems to be less smooth. It doesn't execute automatically, first the `return` at the top would have to be removed. One can look at the code that way before possibly running it. Odd how jQuery does a better job than leaving it to the rendering engine itself.

Comment: ok i think this could work, i tried using pure css before it works but the problem is the animation is not consistent and will overlap after few loops

Comment: This might be a rare case where `setInterval` is preferable over `requestAnimationFrame`, that could keep it more consistent. I dont think it would be much of an issue - I did a desktop performance check and the code seems to run quite smoothly at 60fps apart from a hicup here or there (which can cause unevenness with `requestAnimationFrame` because it delays).

Comment: Yes I just realize this looks heavy on mobile I forgot to check the mobile version on the site where it implements that code it barely pass 20fps. I guess I can't create a smooth version of this one. Tried using the font awesome heart icon + css animation it works for few loops then starts to become inconsistent.

Comment: I'm having a minor brainstorm whether it might be possible to scale the parent instead and perhaps use only one or two elements to be animated. That could be a lot more lightweight. Not sure yet though, I'll let you know if I come up with anything worthwhile.